# CS50 Scrabble | Code goes wrong only with "QUESTION!" word

Tags: c, cs50

programming buddies. I hope everyone is ok.

I'm doing the Scrabble exercise from CS50 and the program runs fine.

BUT... when you type "Question!" or "Question?" as the first word, it simple cannot identify the "Q" as a letter anymore and therefore pontuates it as zero.

Am i doing something wrong?

I tried to printf the output right after the assignment of letters from words to points, and it seems that there is something wrong there, but i cannot figure out what.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet

int POINTS[] = {1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 8, 8, 5, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 4, 4, 10, 10, 0};
char LETTERS[] = {'A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'F', 'f', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'M', 'm', 'N', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'P', 'p', 'Q', 'q', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'V', 'v', 'W', 'w', 'X', 'x', 'Y', 'y', 'Z', 'z', '\0'};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    int lcounter = 0;
    int counter;
    int index1;
    int index2;
    
    // Get input words from both players
    
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");
    
    // FIND LENGTH OF WORD STRINGS
    
    int length_word1 = strlen(word1);
    int length_word2 = strlen(word2);

    // FIND CHARS OF STRINGS IN ARRAY AND ASSIGN VALUE
    
    string cword1 = word1;
    string cword2 = word2;
    
    int word1_counter = length_word1 - 1;
    int word2_counter = length_word2 - 1;
    int w1index[word1_counter];
    int w2index[word2_counter];
    
    for (counter=0; counter < 53; counter ++)
    {
        if (cword1[word1_counter] == LETTERS[counter])
        {
            w1index[word1_counter] = counter;
            word1_counter--;
            counter = -1;
        }
        else if (word1_counter < 0)
        {
            counter = 54;
        }
        else if (counter == 52)
        {
            w1index[word1_counter] = 52;
            word1_counter--;
            counter = -1;
        }
    }
    
    for (counter=0; counter < 53; counter ++)
    {
        if (cword2[word2_counter] == LETTERS[counter])
        {
            w2index[word2_counter] = counter;
            word2_counter--;
            counter = -1;
        }
        else if (word2_counter < 0)
        {
            counter = 54;
        }
        else if (counter == 52)
        {
            w2index[word2_counter] = 52;
            word2_counter--;
            counter = -1;
        }        
    }
    
    // Score both words
    int score1;
    int score2;
    
    for (counter = 0; counter < length_word1; counter ++)
    {
        score1 = score1 + POINTS[w1index[counter]];
    }
    for (counter = 0; counter < length_word2; counter ++)
    {
        score2 = score2 + POINTS[w2index[counter]];
    }
    // TODO: Print the winner
    if (score1 > score2)
    {
        printf("Player 1 wins!");
    }
    else if (score1 < score2)
    {
        printf("Player 2 wins!");
    }
    else if (score1 == score2)
    {
        printf("Tie!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to suggest that this would be much easier to reason about if you had broken out some of it into smaller functions. Maybe `score_for_letter` that converts an ASCII char into an int representing the value of that letter.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will try it right after understand what went wrong with this code. I'm stuck with it because it seems to work with every other word, but when we try words that start with "Q" and end with "!" or "?", this bug happens.

Comment: Making your code easier to reason about might help you solve _this_ problem. If you move the code to get the numeric value of a single letter out into a function, you can make sure that always works. Then you can write a function that gets the numeric value of a word. And you can make sure that always works. All big problems are just collections of little ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I understood your algorithm.

There are two errors. The first is here:

```
int word1_counter = length_word1 - 1;
int word2_counter = length_word2 - 1;
int w1index[word1_counter];
int w2index[word2_counter];
```

You're not reserving enough space for the size intended.
So the second loop (the one that fills `w2index`) will actually overwrite the last member from `w1index` when it's filling the first member from `w2index`.
Change these lines to:

```
int word1_counter = length_word1 - 1;
int word2_counter = length_word2 - 1;
int w1index[word1_counter + 1];
int w2index[word2_counter + 1];
```

The other error is here:

```
// Score both words
int score1;
int score2;
```

The variables are not initialized. Change to:

```
// Score both words
int score1 = 0;
int score2 = 0;
```

Variables `lcounter`, `index1` and `index2` are not used. Remove them.

The names `word*_counter` are not very good because you're actually using them as indexes... You could use `break` to exit the loops and break down/simplify the code much more. But I see you're still beginning so it's easy to overcomplicate... It's fine though. It takes time. The beauty is that with more experience we always tend to make these things simpler!

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked.

I did not attend to the loop container size.

I'll read about break.

Thank you once again for the help you gave me